# How to invert a signal after inverting voltage divider

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, analog, voltage-divider, inverting-amplifier

I need to bring the voltage from 0-5 V to 0-1 V so I'm using an op amp, for linearity, in my design. The inverting op amp has a gain = \$-R_1/R_2\$. My output signal is inverted, but I want a non-inverting output. I can add another inverting op amp with unity gain. Is there another way to do it?

[image]

Comment: Manny, you will likely want to cope a little better with bias currents than your schematic illustrates (though perhaps you are only showing a behavioral idea.) You haven't specified your accuracy requirements, if any, or precision needs. Nor what the output much drive. I agree that using resistor dividers may present problems, including initial inaccuracy due to tolerance interactions.

Comment: Jonk, I agree, I'm feeding this input to a XADC of an FPGA where each bit is = 244 µV.

Answer (score 2):

That way.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEAlfJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If you don't like the divider, then you have to use 2 op amps. But you need also a dual power supply +/-.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feDDkO.png)</sup>

Comment: I'm trying avoid a simple voltage divider https://www.tekscan.com/blog/flexiforce/voltage-divider-or-op-amp-circuit-which-should-you-choose#:~:text=Can%20be%20more%20cost-effective,and%2For%20the%20feedback%20resistor.

Comment: The op-amp buffer prevents the non-linearity with load discussed on the Tekscan web page. You've given us 2 gain requirements: your diagram shows a gain of -0.5 and the first diagram in the answer shows a gain of +0.5 but your text states a gain requirement of +0.2. For the first circuit you'll need to use a modern op-amp with inputs that go down to the negative supply rail (i.e. not a 741) or provide a bipolar power supply.

Comment: @Manny - what is being shown here is a buffered divider, not just a simple divider. What does the output go to?

Comment: Kevin, it is going to a XADC of an FPGA but, first it passes through an AAF filter.

Answer (score 0):

A voltage divider followed by a unity-gain buffer would do it. Can increase resistor values if you want less dissipation. If you don't want to load the signal at all, use a unity-gain buffer before the voltage divider as well.

[image]